# Flink 1.11 with debezium-json format

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

In Flink 1.11, I'm trying `debezium-format` and the following should work, right?  I'm trying to follow docs [1]

```
    TableResult products = bsTableEnv.executeSql(
            "CREATE TABLE products (\n" +
                    "  id BIGINT,\n" +
                    "  name STRING,\n" +
                    "  description STRING,\n" +
                    "  weight DECIMAL(10, 2)\n" +
                    ") WITH (\n" +
                    " 'connector' = 'kafka',\n" +
                    " 'topic' = 'dbserver1.inventory.products',\n" +
                    " 'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9092',\n" +
                    " 'properties.group.id' = 'testGroup',\n" +
                    "'scan.startup.mode'='earliest-offset',\n" +
                    " 'format' = 'debezium-json'" +
                    ")"
    );

    bsTableEnv.executeSql("SHOW TABLES").print(); // This seems to work; 
    bsTableEnv.executeSql("SELECT id FROM products").print();
```

Output Snippet / Exception:

```
+------------+
| table name |
+------------+
|   products |
+------------+
1 row in set
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: AppendStreamTableSink doesn't support consuming update and delete changes which is produced by node TableSourceScan(table=[[default_catalog, default_database, products]], fields=[id, name, description, weight])
```

I have verified Debezium setup and there are messages in the `dbserver1.inventory.products` topic.  I'm able to read from Kafka topics in Flink using other approaches, but as previously described, I'm hoping to get the `debezium-json` format to work.

Also, I understand Flink 1.12 introduces new Kafka Upsert connector, but I'm stuck using 1.11 for now.

I'm pretty new to Flink, so entirely possible I'm missing something obvious here.

Thanks in advance

[1] https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/table/connectors/formats/debezium.html

Answer (score 0):

Asked too soon, it seems.  In case it possibly helps someone else, I was able to get it to work with

```java
Table results = bsTableEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT id, name FROM products");
bsTableEnv.toRetractStream(results, Row.class).print();
```